# Load page with anchor centered - Browser scrolling to top after document ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a page loads with an anchor (fragment) in the url, instead of the default behavior of scrolling so the anchored element is at the top of the screen, I want it centered.

The following does what I want:

```
var $targetDiv = $(window.location.hash);

if ($targetDiv) {
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.scrollTop($targetDiv.offset().top - ($window.height() / 2));
}
```

However, when I run this on document.ready, 9 times out of 10 the page loads with the element at the top, rather than centered.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptnmq/4/) (note I'm using `<div>`with an id, rather than an `<a>` with a name, but the effect was the same)

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/ptnmq/4/show#middle) of going to the page with the #middle anchor.

If I had to guess, it seems the browser is doing it's job and scrolling to the top of the element **after** the ready event fires.  What's the correct way of loading the page with the anchored element centered?

Comment: If anyone has found a reference relating to these order of events (e.g., "When does the browser do the scrolling to an anchor/id?") I would appreciate them sharing it since I have encountered a related scenario. In my case, there are tabs on a page that append ids like #tab-1 to the URL, but we do not want to page to scroll down to the tabs on load. window.setTimeout( function() { $(window).scrollTop(0); }, 0); seems to work but feels ugly to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an `!` to any links to anchors I wanted to have centered, and updated my code to strip the `!`:

```
var $targetDiv = $(window.location.hash.replace(/!/, ''));

if ($targetDiv) {
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.scrollTop($targetDiv.offset().top - ($window.height() / 2));
}
```

So for example, browsing to `someUrl.com/Index#!foo` the browser would ignore the `#!foo` and the page would scroll so `<div id="foo">` was centered.

Another partial solution was to run the above code on window load, rather than document ready.  Unfortunately, then the browser would scroll twice, once so the div showed on top, then again with it centered.